# no setea correcto el hint de un TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android-studio, xml

Estoy intentando hacer el hint dinamico. de un TextInputLayout

mi xml

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_nombre_selecc"
                        style="@style/outlinedTextInputEditText.Multilines"

                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:text="" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

como verán no le asigno ningún hint.

ahora lo inicializo en android

```
  TextInputEditText txt_nombre_selecc = findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre_selecc);
```

seteo el hint según una condición

```
  if (tipo == 1){

            txt_nombre_selecc.setHint("información 1");
        }
else{
 txt_nombre_selecc.setHint("información 2");
}
```

hasta acá es correcto, lo hace... sin problemas.

pero luego seteo el valor del text

```
 txt_nombre_selecc.setText("aca va el nombre");
```

el TextInputLayout ya no muestra el hint y solo muestra el texto.

que es lo que falta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El hint debe setearse en el `TextInputLayout` no en el `TextInputEditText`. Ejemplo:

```
TextInputEditText txt_nombre_selecc = findViewById(R.id.txt_nombre_selecc);
TextInputLayout layout_nombre = findViewById(R.id.layout_nombre);
if (tipo == 1) {
    layout_nombre.setHint("información 1");
} else {
    layout_nombre.setHint("información 2");
}
txt_nombre_selecc.setText("aca va el nombre");
```

El `setHint()` del `TextInputEditText` es igual al `setPlaceholderText()` del `TextInputLayout`. Es decír que setea un texto que sólo es visible cuando el editText está vacío.

Comment: Muchas gracias.. me funciono. y buen dato sobre el TextInputEditText  he estado haciendo mal.. ahora ya se donde colocarlo correctamente.